# Spawn a thread and worker queue only if resource is busy

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, race-condition

Hoping someone can help me design this correctly.

In my TCP code, I have a SendMessage() function that tries to write to the wire. I am trying to design the call so that it moves to a producer/consumer model if a lot of concurrent requests happen, but at the same time, stays single-threaded if there are no concurrent requests (for maximum performance).

I'm struggling on how to design this without race conditions because there is no way to move locks between threads.

What I have so far is something like (pseudo-coded):

```
SendMessage(msg) {

    if(Monitor.TryEnter(wirelock,200)) {

       try{
          sendBytes(msg);
       }
       finally {
          Monitor.Exit...
       }
   }
   else {

     _SomeThreadSafeQueue.add(msg)

     Monitor.TryEnter(consumerlock,..

          Task.Factory.New(ConsumerThreadMethod....
    }
}


ConsumerThreadMethod() {

   lock (wirelock) {

         while(therearemessagesinthequeue)

               sendBytes...

   }

}
```

Any obvious race conditions?

EDIT: Found a flaw in the last one. How about this instead?

```
SendMessage(msg) {

    if(Monitor.TryEnter(wirelock)) {

       try{
          sendBytes(msg);
       }
       finally {
          Monitor.Exit...
       }
   }
   else {

         _SomeThreadSafeQueue.add(msg)

        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadcounter) == 1)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConsumerThreadMethod());

        }
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadcounter);

        }      
    }
}


ConsumerThreadMethod() {

     while(therearemessagesinthequeue)
           lock (wirelock) {
               sendBytes...
            }
      }

     Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadcounter);
}
```

So basically using the interlocked counter as a way to only ever spawn one thread (if necessary)

Comment: Dont forget: KISS. Just use a threadsafe queue and one (or n, depending on max connection count and cores available) dedicated sender thread. A lockless queue will add very little latency compared to the wire latency.

Comment: actuallyi  noticed a flaw in my design. two threads could start a new thread since the lock has to be released after the Factor.New call, since i can't transfer the lock to the consumerthread

Comment: I guess I have to rewrite my classes to allow a single thread to go through all the queues (one for each connection) eh? otherwise it could be hundreds of blocked queues (not sure how the threadpool handles that)

Comment: Your new example has a race. The consumer thread can be finished but not yet decremented. Then a new task won't have a consumer thread to handle it.

Comment: dang.. you're right. there could be a context switch between the end of the while() and the Interlocked.Decrement. This is tough. Any ideas? Really like the idea of switching to consumer model only in bursts (and thus allowing the thread to be released once the queue is empty)

Comment: Seems I need to be able to create a lock in one thread and release it an another for this to be done cleanly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No obvious races but TryEnter is a cause for some serious idle time. I actually think that using a consumer thread all the time is the best solution. If there is little to do, the overhead will be really small (the consumer thread will be asleep when not working, if designed correctly).

Now you create a new task for each sent message, resulting in huge contention on the lock, since you are using a while loop in the consumer thread.

EDIT: Since you are using non-blocking sockets, a single consumer thread should be enough to handle all send requests. The throughput of a single thread is higher than your network. If you have more consumers it's hard to make sure that no two consumer threads send on the same socket, without serializing everything using a mutex. I don't think switching between single-threaded and multi-threaded is a good idea.

Your current "multithreaded" solution does not give you any performance gain since all work is protected using the same mutex. It will be as slow, or slower, than a single thread.

Comment: Are you suggesting one consumer thread for each connection? Or a master thread that goes through the connection queues one by one (on the client side it makes no difference but the server could have 1000s of connections)

Comment: Don't you have one thread per connection to receive data? Or are you using non-blocking sockets?